# Algorithm for precedence related job allocation

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

Suppose we have a set of jobs. 
Some jobs are related to others for example Job (a) has to finish for Job(b) to begin. 
Some other jobs are not related, that means can run in parallel. We have a limited number of machines much less than the number of jobs. Is there an algorithm that can assign these jobs to machines so that we minimize the maximum load on any single machine (makespan)

Comment: maybe try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may want to look at the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).